# Why isn't my Canon 60D saving images to SD with pics taken using swivel screen/viewer?

Tags: canon, canon-60d, live-view

My Canon 60D does not save photos to the SD card when I take photos while using the swivel screen/viewer. It happens with different SD cards, so I don't think it is caused by a defective SD card.

Comment: Are you absolutely 100% sure that you're actually taking a photo? A DSLR takes a *lot* longer to focus when using live view ("the swivel screen") than it does when using the viewfinder, and if it doesn't get a focus lock (in some modes) it won't take a photo.

Comment: @tedm - does the shutter click and nothing gets saved? or is the shutter not clicking when using the swivel screen to focus?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you are using quick focus and it isn't actually taking the photos.  When you are using live view with quick focus, the mirror will engage to redirect the image path to the PDAF sensor.  It will then focus and take the image and then the mirror will go back in to hiding.  This ends up making a bit of an odd pattern of sounds and it is easy to think that it is done taking an image when it is actually just starting.

I actually had this occur while shooting on my 5D Mark iii in live view during my sister's wedding and we had to rely on the professional photographer that was covering it officially for images because none of mine actually took, despite sounding like they had.  (Up to that point, I had never used LiveView due to the lag issues and preferring the view finder.)

Comment: Thanks for some good suggestions and answers that I will have to look into. I will get back and tell you what I found once I've had a chance to test these suggestions. Thanks Again